# Infer function argument types from a list of module names

Tags: typescript

I have a lot of old `.js` files that can not be migrated to `.ts` files at the moment. I'm adding `.d.ts` files to add types, but using the types is a problem because the files import each other through requireJs, like this:

```
define(['moduleA', 'moduleB'], function(moduleA, moduleB) {
    // ...
});
```

I want the function arguments, `moduleA` and `moduleB`, to be properly typed in this case. Since the module names (`'moduleA', 'moduleB'`) are customized in a runtime config file, TypeScript can't really help connecting the dots.

So I have an idea that is to augment the type of `define`, so that it expects a list of module names from the first argument, map them to module types defined in a mapping interface, then type the function arguments to the second argument to be that list of module types.

I got the basic proof of concept working:

```
/**
 * This interface is used to map module names to their types.
 */
export interface RequireJsModules {
    foo: boolean;
    bar: string;
}

export type RequireJsModulify<T extends string[]> = {
    [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends keyof RequireJsModules
        ? RequireJsModules[T[P]]
        : unknown
};

// This line is for testing `RequireJsModulify`.
type Foo = RequireJsModulify<['foo', 'bar', 'wut']>;
```

This screenshot shows `RequireJsModulify` is working. Type of `Foo` is a tuple of correct module types based on the tuple of module names.
[image: Screenshot of type inference of type Foo is [number, string, unknown].]

Where I'm stuck at is the `define` function signature:

```
declare global {
    export function define<T extends string[], U extends RequireJsModulify<T>>(
        deps: T,
        moduleFactory: ((...args: U) => any)
    ): void;
}
```

The idea is that the arguments to `moduleFactory` must be the mapped module types based on type argument `T` which is an arbitrary list of strings. If an string is a key of the mapping interface `RequireJsModules`, then the corresponding function argument should have that module type, otherwise the argument should have type `unknown`.

I have this test case:

```
describe('requirejs type', () => {
    it('should call the module factory with the correct types corresponding to the dependencies', () => {
        // There should be no type errors below.
        define(['foo', 'bar', 'wut'], function(foo, bar, wut) {
            const fooExpected: boolean = foo;
            const barExpected: string = bar;
            const wutExpected: unknown = wut;

            console.log({ fooExpected, barExpected });
        });
    });
});
```

If the type for `define` works the way I wanted, then the first argument `foo` should have type `boolean`, the second argument `bar` should have type `string`, while the third one should be `unknown`.

**But They are all `unknown` at the moment.**

And therefore:

[image: Screenshot of type error about assigning unknown type to boolean type.]

I'm using TypeScript 3.9.7.

Any ideas why it's not working?

Comment: It seems the `...args: U` part is mixing all the types from tuple `U` together, essentially being `...args: (string | number | unknown)[]`, which equals `...args: unknown[]`.

Comment: It seems like the example input `['foo', 'bar', 'wut']` has type `('foo' | 'bar' | 'wut')[]`, which seems to be the reason that `U` becomes `(string | number | unknown)[]`.